How do I setup a vue slot type as a simple string not a component
I want to be able to pass a string as a slot into a vue component. Define on the vue component that the slot is supposed to be a string and then use that string both in the template and in the script tags. There is a defineSlots function in the docs but every single example just keeps showing how to use it with objects like this

Source: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineslots
I want to do something like this.

But this doesnt seem to work. Surley there has to be a way to define a slot on vue thats just a plain string?
Heres a stackblitz that shows pretty clearly what Im trying to do and what I want.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mouih9?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FSlotsButton.vue&terminal=dev

I think using a prop is the more appropriate solution, especially if you're trying to define/limit the incoming value. Is there a reason you must use a slot for a simple string? Regardless, maybe this example using useSlots gets closer to what you want.

@yoduh I dont like that I cant define the type but I guess this is the best answer anyhow. The reason I want to use slot instead of prop is because the text is describing whats going into the html node and so it makes a lot of sence to avoid crowding the props by using the slot channel where it makes sense to do so. Overly relying on props for data communication is a codesmell imo. Its why compound components are so great. Because it lets you avoid props by using children as props

" Overly relying on props for data communication is a codesmell imo" - not in Vue. Would be different in React, for instance, where anything can be a slot aka children prop

@EstusFlask I think it holds true in any component pattern reguardless of framework. You have 2 channels to send data through. Slots and props. Loadbalancing data between them as appropriate is always going to improve readability. Thats more to do with human brains and their ability to read data in groups then it has to do with frameworks. So I 100% think Vue should invest in making it easy to use slots like this. Anyhow, guess it doesnt matter. I pretty much have my answer

@SamuelM.Bednarz Possible uses are specific to how frameworks work internally and their limitations. E.g. it's idiomatic to pass elements (Vue's vnodes) through props in React, but in Vue named slots are reserved for this purpose, which React doesn't have, etc. And yes, this boils down to the answer. Typechecking in Vue templates is seriously lacking

Unfortunately Vue doesn't support typing slot content:

The return type is currently ignored and can be any, but we may leverage it for slot content checking in the future.

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineslots
Also note that slots are much slower than props
